# How to extract email attachment from Outlook mail items received today?

Tags: vba, ms-access

The code below is simple and works however, it needs to be modified so that when it looks in the outlook folder it only looks at mail items with a received date = today.  I've spent hours trying to fix this.

```vb
Sub Command0_Click()
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Dim OlMail As Object
    Dim OlItems As Object
    Dim OlFolder As Object
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim CurrentDate As String
    CurrentDate = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD") '
    Dim aFile As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

    strFolder = "H:\TEST_DROP\" ' Folder where saving attachments

    '''Outlook folder path
    'Change Folder to your email adddress
    'Change inbox to your subfolder in the your main mailbox
    Set OlFolder = OlApp.getnamespace("MAPI").Folders("MyEmail@my_company.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("TEST_ML")

    Set OlItems = OlFolder.Items

    ''looks in each email in that folder and saves attachments in strFolder
    '''THE CODE HERE NEEDS TO BE MODIFIED TO ONLY LOOK AT THE EMAILS WITH A RECEIVED DATE OF TODAY only....
    For Each OlMail In OlItems
        If OlMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
            For J = 1 To OlMail.Attachments.Count
                OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).SaveAsFile strFolder & OlMail.Attachments.Item(J).FileName
            Next J
        End If
    Next

    Set OlFolder = Nothing
    Set OlItems = Nothing
    Set OlMail = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing

    ''''RENAME FILE WITH CURRENT DATE SUFFIX
    Name "H:\TEST_DROP\Remittance_YYYYMMDD.csv" As "H:\TEST_DROP\Remittance_" & CurrentDate & ".csv"

End Sub
```

Comment: You are specifying the name in your `.SaveAsFile` so you don't need to rename the file later. Just name it correctly the first time around.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  All fixed.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each mail item has a property `OlMail.ReceivedTime`

You need to compare that to `Now()`

Like this:

```
If (Now() - OlMail.ReceivedTime) < 1 Then
```

This works because the result of this evaluation is the number of days between the two. Time is a fraction of a day.

Comment: Thank you HackSlash.  How would I incorporate that into the existing code?  Can I nest If statements?

Comment: Let me give it a shot.

Comment: If OlMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        If (Now() - OlMail.ReceivedTime) < 1 Then
...  
    End If
End If

Comment: It saving images from email signature also. How to avoid/ignore saving image from email signature?

Comment: @Harun24HR, please open your own question. This is a comment on an answer. Not a place to ask questions.

Comment: You can use the Kill command, for example,                                                                                            
         Kill "H:\TEST_DROP\\*.JPG"

Comment: @ORLANDOVAZQUEZ, please don't save and then kill files you don't need. Just skip them.